# Click does not work when using Python-Selenium to filter out information

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm trying to download runners' information from New York Marathon (See: http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers) using Python-Selenium. I want to filter this information by gender and age group, so I wrote the following code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers')
browser.maximize_window()

gender_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dropdown dropdown-
main short-filter']")
gender_menu.click()
gender_menu.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@role='menu']/li[3]").click()

age_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dropdown dropdown-
main short-filter ages-filter']")
age_menu.click()
age_menu.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@role='menu']/li[3]").click()
```

The problem is that the part `age_menu.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@role='menu']/li[3]").click()` gives me the exepction "Element Not Visible" when I use `/li[1]`, `/li[2]`, or `/li[3]`, BUT NOT when I use `/li[4]` or a higher index.

Can it be that `.click` gives this exception because I use it also when choosing gender? Notice that gender has 3 options and I can only filter by age group since the fourth group. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you're scraping for data, why not use Beautiful Soup?

Comment: @sircapsalot Because I first need to click in each runner to load the data, beautiful soup cannot do that (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: ok :)  was just wondering as i'm unaware of the app you are testing. if you need to actually trigger ajax, then yes. selenium is definitely suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if below implementation is what you are looking for but it works for me

```
age_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dropdown dropdown-
main short-filter ages-filter']")
age_menu.click()
ages = age_menu.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul[role="menu"]>li>a')
for age in ages:
if age.text == 'AGE: 20-24':
    age.click()
    break
```

Comment: That works! I don't get why this is so different from what I was doing